# Intercept page load to show only a portion of the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here is the situation: I am building a chrome extension that injects a sidebar to a page (simple HTML) when the browser icon is clicked. I also use message passing to check if the button was already clicked for a domain name so that I automatically (re)display the sidebar.

I am wondering if it is possible to intercept the loading of the page content so that my sidebar loads first, then the actual page.

Comment: it's not really possible to inject content into HTML that hasn't been loaded yet...

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. I thought there might be something in chrome API that will allow to do such a thing..Or a hack maybe

Comment: I think you can execute before the loading of the page (see chrome doc), but you won't have access to the HTML of the page at this point.
What's wrong with injecting the code after the page load?

Comment: Ah I understand. It's a matter of aesthetics, the layout of the page loads first and it's stretching to the whole width of the screen, then  it shrinks leaving place to the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

If you inject at `"document_start"`, your code executes before *any* DOM is constructed.

You can then, for instance, hook a DOM Mutation Observer to watch for some kind of parent node to be inserted, say `<body>`, and add your UI then.

Comment: Ok, great! I'll try that  out.